# Can i pass a variable to the kohana controller action_index in order to create an if else statement there?

Tags: php, rest, variables, controller, kohana

I am trying pass a variable from the index.php file to the action_index in order to change between queries.

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');                                                                                                                                               

class Controller_Rest_Chart extends Controller {                                                                                                                                                           

    public function action_index()                                                                                                                                                                         
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    if ($test < 2)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        $result = DB::query(Database::SELECT, "SELECT date AS label,sales_order AS value FROM chart_sales where date >= '{$_GET['start']}'::DATE AND date <= '{$_GET['end']}'::DATE order by date desc")   
            ->execute()                                                                                                                                                                                    
            ->as_array();                                                                                                                                                                                  
         else    
            $result = DB::query(Database::SELECT, "SELECT date AS label,sales_order AS value FROM chart_sales where date >= '{$_GET['start']}'::DATE AND date <= '{$_GET['end']}'::DATE order by date asc")   
            ->execute()                                                                                                                                                                                    
            ->as_array(); 

            echo (json_encode($result));     

    }                                                                                                                                                                                                      

}
```

Comment: How does your definition of the variable in index.php look like?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can .I suggest you read about routing here : http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing

if you are using the default route then if you can send the variable you want like this

```
<ur website>/Rest_Chart/index/2
```

and fetch it like this

```
$test = $this->request->param('id');
```

P.S: [off topic] not sure about ur coice of controller name ... using'_' means a subdirectory in kohana you should use camelcases .

Comment: Why not use _ for cleaning up my directories with subdirs? :)

Comment: you can use '_' if u really mean subdirs sure . was just pointing out if this wasn't the case and Rest_Chart was the name of one file then CamelCase will be more appropriate .

Comment: Thanks for the input. I solved the problem with writing an if else statement in the view/index.php file.